# Copy a large table to a different table efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

There is a large table and I need to move the contents of it to a table which has a different structure. The tables are on different databases. For this I am using a PHP script. But the script does not work with the way I wanted. It over-copies and never stops. Maybe it is a noobish and simple question but right now my head is spinning, from trying but I can not put my finger on the problem. And this job needs to be done immediately. I will be glad if you help. Here the code snippet:

```
function copy_table()
{
    $this->load->database();

    $num_rows = $this->db->get('orj_table')->num_rows();

    $offset = 0;
    $limit = 500;

    while ($offset <= $num_rows)
    {       
        $this->load->database();

        //Query for original table
        //......

        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $records = $this->db->get('orj_table')->result_array();
        $this->db->close();

        //Open a connection to new database. 

        $this->db_new = $this->load->database('new', TRUE);

        foreach($records as $record)
        {   
            $data1 = $record['data1'];
            $data2 = $record['data2'];

            $datas[] = array('data1 => $record['data1'],
                    'data2 => $record['data2']
                    );
        }

        //Insert 500 records at one time with "insert_batch"
        $sorgu = $this->db_yeni->insert_batch('new_table', datas);

        $this->db->close();
        $offset += 500;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want efficiency, start by not using PHP.  Try using `mysqldump`.

Comment: I don't know why it over-copies and never stops, but you seem to miss a `$` before datas in the line that calls the `insert_batch` function.

Comment: Concerning your "overcopy", it comes from the fact that you never unset the $datas[] array that will get filled over and over. Hence, it will reinsert the whole array every time in the while loop.

Comment: @Tom: Thans Tom! Yes that is definitely the problem!

Comment: No problem ;) Been there, done that. Lost my head over that problem before ! But you should definetely look into the pure Mysql solution !

Answer (score 5):

Try using this simple mysql query instead :

`INSERT INTO different_table (SELECT col1, col3, col4 FROM initial_table)`

Comment: There is 500.000 records. Will memory be managed automatically by MySQL?

Comment: Definitely more than using a PHP script to do 1000 batch queries with no sleep() ;)

Comment: Why would you prefer a subquery over MySQL's [`INSERT ... SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)?

Comment: @ObscureRobot What subquery ?

Comment: `(SELECT col1, col3, col4 FROM initial_table)` is a subquery

Comment: INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]. Is it ?

Answer (score 1):

Why use PHP, or most importantly CodeIgniter?

You should just do something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE `newtable`
    SELECT * FROM `othertable`;
```

.. of course with this you can select what you want, join, define new column names etc, and whatever you select out will be placed into a new table.

If your destination table already exists, change the `CREATE` to `INSERT`.